# AttributeError:'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-2to3

Trying to import a code from python2 to python 3 and this problem happens

```
    <ipython-input-53-e9f33b00348a> in aesEncrypt(text, secKey)
     43 def aesEncrypt(text, secKey):
     44     pad = 16 - len(text) % 16
---> 45     text = text.encode("utf-8") + (pad * chr(pad)).encode("utf-8")
     46     encryptor = AES.new(secKey, 2, '0102030405060708')
     47     ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
```

> AttributeError:'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

If I remove `.encode("utf-8")` the error is "can't concat str to bytes". Apparently `pad*chr(pad)` seems to be a byte string. It cannot use `encode()`

```
    <ipython-input-65-9e84e1f3dd26> in aesEncrypt(text, secKey)
     43 def aesEncrypt(text, secKey):
     44     pad = 16 - len(text) % 16
---> 45     text = text.encode("utf-8") + (pad * chr(pad))
     46     encryptor = AES.new(secKey, 2, '0102030405060708')
     47     ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
```

> TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

However, the weird thing is that if i just try the part along. encode() works fine.

```
text = { 'username': '', 'password': '', 'rememberLogin': 'true' }
text=json.dumps(text)
print(text)
pad = 16 - len(text) % 16 
print(type(text))
text = text + pad * chr(pad) 
print(type(pad * chr(pad)))
print(type(text))
text = text.encode("utf-8") + (pad * chr(pad)).encode("utf-8") 
print(type(text))

{"username": "", "password": "", "rememberLogin": "true"}
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: `chr` returns a string that gets multiplied and encoded as bytes. The problem here is that `text` is bytes. How are you calling `aesEncrypt`? You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Python2 strings are implicitly bytes objects while Python3 strings are unicode. So this makes sense. This looks like the right way to do it to me - the way you added .encode('utf-8').  But this won't be backward compatible with Python2 - is that what the issue is? @RoyDai

Comment: Maybe a portable way to control the codec is to import `codec` and using it's `encode()` and `decode()` module functions.

Comment: `pad = 16 - len("dummy") % 16;
(pad * chr(pad)).encode('utf-8')
b'\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b\x0b'` Works fine on Python3.. unless there were pad bytes it couldn't encode.

Comment: @Todd Thanks very much for the reply. I tried .encode('utf-8') works for isolated sessions but it didnt work for first case i dont now why.

Comment: Put a print in it or trap it with the debugger and examine what value it isn't handling. @RoyDai

Comment: If you put my conversion function in your code, just temporarily to reproduce the error.. the exception message will tell you what type it's not able to handle. I'm guessing `None` might be being passed in. @RoyDai And maybe set your IDE (Eclipse or whatever) to break on exceptions.. so you can examine the stack.

Comment: Wait a minute - you're setting text to a dictionary. encode is for unicode strings - it won't work on dictionaries.

Comment: @Todd Thanks for the follow up. Sorry for the confusion. I have posted another question here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371553/typeerror-cant-concat-str-to-bytes-when-converting-python-2-to-3-with-encrypti). I realise it is more of a "cannot concat str to bytes" problem as "pad*chr(pad)" seem to be a str but byte string or something.

Comment: Have you read over my answer below about how strings are different on Py2 vs Py3?

Comment: @Todd Thanks for the ans. I read and I kind of understand there are these difference. Do you mean I shall add a converter function or is there an simpler way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't know if a stringlike object is a Python 2 string (bytes) or Python 3 string (unicode). You could have a generic converter.

Python3 shell:

```
>>> def to_bytes(s):
...     if type(s) is bytes:
...         return s
...     elif type(s) is str or (sys.version_info[0] < 3 and type(s) is unicode):
...         return codecs.encode(s, 'utf-8')
...     else:
...         raise TypeError("Expected bytes or string, but got %s." % type(s))
...         
>>> to_bytes("hello")
b'hello'
>>> to_bytes("hello".encode('utf-8'))
b'hello'
```

On Python 2 both these expressions evaluate to `True`: `type("hello") == bytes` and `type("hello") == str`. And `type(u"hello") == str` evaluates to `False`, while `type(u"hello") == unicode` is `True`.

On Python 3 `type("hello") == bytes` is `False`, and `type("hello") == str` is `True`. And `type("hello") == unicode` raises a `NameError` exception since `unicode` isn't defined on 3.

Python 2 shell:

```
>>> to_bytes(u"hello")
'hello'
>>> to_bytes("hello")
'hello'
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Todd, he solved issue. 
`(pad * chr(pad))`is bytes while problems lies with `aesEncrypt(text, secKey)`. It has been called twice with `text` as `str` for the first time while as `bytes` for the second time.

The solution is to make sure that the input `text` is of `str` type.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first parameter of `AES.new` is bytes/bytearray/memoryview, and I assume that `text` is already of type `bytes`, then we just have to convert the pad part from `unicode` to `bytes`.

```py
text = text + (pad * chr(pad)).encode("utf-8")
```

To be extra safe, you may encode `text` conditionally before concatenating with pad.

```py
if not isinstance(text, bytes):
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @Todd how about checking if it is not bytes? Kind of lazy, but would work given the input is either bytes or unicode

Comment: you caught me as I just finished up dissecting this difference - testing if it's not bytes would leave the possibility it could be None or another type that isn't a str or unicode object. See if you can find the answer in my notes on my answer post. let me know if i accounted for what case you have in mind.